# Change variables from Main method using oither classes in Java?

Tags: java, variables, methods, program-entry-point

I'm making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I want to change the variables in the Main method using other classes. How would I do this? Here's my code.

**Main Method**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RPSApp 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int userThrow, cpuThrow;
    final int ROCK = 1, PAPER = 2, SCISSORS = 3;
    String rockName = "Rock", paperName = "Paper", scissorsName = "Scissors";
    String nameOfGame = "Rock, Paper, Scissors";
    String userThrowEng, cpuThrowEng;
    int outcome;
    int langSel = 1;
    String userInput;
    boolean keepPlaying = true;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();
    LanguageHandler language = new LanguageHandler();
    GameHandler game = new GameHandler();

    System.out.println("Select Language");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("(1) US\n(2) UK");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(">");

    langSel = input.nextInt();

    if (langSel == 2)
    {
        language.setBritish();
    }

    System.out.println("Welcome to " + nameOfGame + "!");
```

**LanguageHandler.java**

```
public class LanguageHandler 
{
    public void setBritish ()
    {
        nameOfGame = "Paper, Scissors, Stone";
        rockName = "Stone";
    }
}
```

This however, does not work. How would I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't. Variables declared in a method are *local* variables - no other code can get at them. You should look at *instance* variables. I suggest you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: You have to declare these variables outside of `main` method as `public static`. Then in `LanguageHandler` you should specify its classname like that: `RPSApp.nameOfGame = ...`.

Comment: @Everv0id Can you show me example code? I'm still learning, but doing what you told me to do made syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java Code**

```
        public class TestProgram {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            {
                int userThrow, cpuThrow;
                final int ROCK = 1, PAPER = 2, SCISSORS = 3;
                String rockName = "Rock", paperName = "Paper", scissorsName = "Scissors";
                String nameOfGame = "Rock, Paper, Scissors";
                String userThrowEng, cpuThrowEng;
                int outcome;
                int langSel = 1;
                String userInput;
                boolean keepPlaying = true;

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                Random generator = new Random();
                LanguageHandler language = new LanguageHandler();

                System.out.println("Select Language");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("(1) US\n(2) UK");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(">");

                langSel = input.nextInt();

                if (langSel == 2) {
                    nameOfGame=language.getNameOfGame();
                }

                System.out.println("Welcome to " + nameOfGame + "!");
            }
        }
    }

public class LanguageHandler {

     String  nameOfGame = "Paper, Scissors, Stone";
     String rockName = "Stone";
    public String getNameOfGame() {
        return nameOfGame;
    }
    public void setNameOfGame(String nameOfGame) {
        this.nameOfGame = nameOfGame;
    }
    public String getRockName() {
        return rockName;
    }
    public void setRockName(String rockName) {
        this.rockName = rockName;
    }


}
```

Comment: Works for me if u add changes to language handler class

Comment: I'm new to Java :) What's the HashMap and alphaMorse things?

Comment: @DigiDuncan edited my code . Now it works the way you want it to work :)

Comment: @DigiDuncan sorry for that I forgot to remove that code, it was from previous program.

Comment: @DigiDuncan let me know if you have any other questions. I am decent in java to help you out.